# Change Git Commit Message

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've made a terrible mistake. Looking back on my git commits, it seems that somehow I've managed to get some incorrect data on each of them.

My git commits, rather than looking like this `username<email@address>` look like `username<mypassword>`. How can I fix this for future commits? I will scrap the password but there it doesn't seem right to continue pushing with this message.

My git email is set to my email address, they're not set to the password. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can use `git filter-branch` to rewrite history, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/50552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a badly set git config. Try running:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Or find `.gitconfig`
To see what's there. You can override with

```
git config --global user.email "notmypassword@address"
```